# Issues setting Icon Colors in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, icons, maps, openstreetmap, openlayers-3

I am experimenting some troubles by trying to assign a color to an icon in Openlayers 3.

I've already taken a look at the [Icon Colors example](https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/examples/icon-color.html) in the Openlayers site, but even with the code we find there it doesn't work. If we click the "Edit" button in the example, a jsfiddle is opened, although we should comment the line where we assign a custom color if we want to see the icon. This is what I have so far:

```
pointInMap.setStyle( new ol.style.Style( {
    image: new ol.style.Icon( ( {
        color: [ 113, 140, 0 ],
        src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/examples/data/dot.png'
    } ) )
} ) );

vectorSource.addFeature(pointInMap);
```

I am defining the color as the [Openlayers 3 API states](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/apidoc/ol.html#.Color) it should be defined, and I also tried some other ways but no one worked at all.

You can find a living jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v89ryfas/). I commented the code where the color assignment was done, but if you uncomment one of these lines you will see that the icon is not even shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got the same issue. You need to add `crossOrigin: 'anonymous',`

```
rome.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
        color: '#8959A8',
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
        src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/examples/data/dot.png'
    }))
}));
```

Please find the corresponding [thread](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/5336#event-658479877http://) and [explanation](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/6349/commits/57342a69128e102868e364baf749cb1dcd41fc0d):

> - Note that icon files need to obey the same origin policy or send proper CORS headers for this to work. When relying on CORS headers, the `ol.style.Icon` must be configured with `crossOrigin: 'anonymous'`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Nice solution with good links! However, although it works on the jsfiddle, I cannot make it work in a real environment. In my local box it's not filled with any color yet :S

Comment: Are you sure to work with a 3.13.0 (or higher) version of Openlayers?

Comment: If you are using an icon from Openlayers, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin :"*" ` are already defined. But if you use an image from your local server or else, you need to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` from your server. I'm stuck with this step, so from there I would not be of much help.

Comment: Thanks, the OpenLayers version used was 3.3.0. I changed it to v3.20.1 (Which is the latest one in the OpenLayers Site, I don't really know where 3.3.0 came from...) and now it works perfectly! :D
No change in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` was needed at all

Answer (score 0):

Why not use svg?

For example : `<svg  width="50" height="50" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="5" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="rbg(113, 140, 0 )"/></svg>`

You can then use it as src:

Here's jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/v89ryfas/3/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! This would be a possible solution, but I want to set a specific picture as similar to the examples as I could.